# Regex to match the start of a string for numbers that are between 10 and 12 in length

Tags: regex

This should match

1233232985 John Doe

This should not match

John Doe 47437363

What I have attempted.
^\d{10-12}

Comment: It should be `{10,12}`, not `{10-12}`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help

"^[0-9]{10}$|^[0-9]{12}$"